# Looking to add venobox in all gallery items in a single custom post type

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I can't get it working.

This is the site of `venobox` `http://lab.veno.it/venobox/` it's a jquery lightbox for images.

I tried in WordPress to add some functions in `functions.php` to make it working in all attachment (gallery) images posted in `single-gallery.php`.

I got the `venobox.min.js` in header but I cant see the `venobox.css` when I see the source.

```
// Register and Enqueue Scripts for venobox in single gallery page
function thegallery_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'venobox-responsive-gallery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/venobox.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('venobox-responsive-gallery');

    if ( is_page_template( 'single-gallery.php' ) ) {
        wp_register_style('venobox-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/venobox.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('venobox-style');
    }

}
// Implement enqueued scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thegallery_enqueue_scripts' );
```

and I used the function below to replace the class bu idnt work

```
add_filter('the_content', 'venobox_add_venobox_lightbox');
function venobox_add_venobox_lightbox($content) {
       global $post;
       $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
       $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 class="venobox" data-gall="gall1" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
       $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
       return $content;
}
```

Can anyone help me in this code? Thank you.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work"...what happened?

Comment: as Im trying to add lightbox using that venobox for all images whn I click on any image in gallery it doesnt open the lightbox, nothing happens